# Why fire-breath dll is not working after Firefox 28?

Tags: c++, firefox, firebreath

I have created a plugin using fire breath. It's working fine in chrome, and up to Firefox 28 version after that its not working. Can you help me to work with updated version too.

Comment: the exception is thrown while calling npapi functions  ngAutofill().set()

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I can do is speculate because you haven't told us what platform you're on, but I believe FireFox 28 is where they started doing 64 bit builds on windows.  Try building your plugin 64 bit and see if it changes anything.